# Compiler Warning - 'std::_Copy_impl' Function call with parameters that may be unsafe

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-warnings

I am working on a project and am really confused with a compiler warning that I'm getting. I'm concerned because I will lose 10% for every compiler warning issued, although the warning seems to be talking about the professor's code below.

```
 template <typename T>
sorted_vector<T>& sorted_vector<T>::operator = (sorted_vector<T> const& src) {
    std::unique_ptr<T> pNewBuffer(new T[src.size()]);
    std::copy(src.beg_, src.end_, pNewBuffer.get());
    delete[] beg_;
    beg_ = pNewBuffer.release();
    end_ = beg_ + src.size();
    cap_ = end_;

    return *this;
}
```

This is the code I am writing to test the function of the assignment operator.

Sample 1:

```
sVec1 = sVec2 = sVec3 = sorted_vector<cont_t>();
```

Sample 2:

```
sorted_vector<cont_t> sVec = sorted_vector<cont_t>();
```

I am getting this in response to code sample one:

```
see reference to function template instantiation 'sorted_vector<cont_t> &sorted_vector<cont_t>::operator =(const sorted_vector<cont_t> &)' being compiled
sorted_vector<cont_t> sVec = sorted_vector<cont_t>();
```

This is what I'm getting for code sample two:

```
see reference to class template instantiation 'sorted_vector<cont_t>' being compiled
```

Thanks for the help. I'm really stuck. I read that this may be due to deprecated code

Comment: [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965.aspx) describes the situation, and also documents how to disable these warnings. TL;DR: define `_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` macro in project settings.

Comment: `sorted_vector<cont_t> sVec = sorted_vector<cont_t>();` is **not** assignment. It's *initialization*.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly my concern. I have no idea why the compiler is complaining about that.

Comment: I imagine there's similar code in the copy constructor.